# Error with option --strip-components when running example from manual of tar command

Tags: shell, tar, archive

When reading the manual of tar command I encountered something wrong with the option `--strip-components`.
The example in the manual is that there is a tar file containing a directory with 3 files. When listed with the tar command it looks like this:

```
$tar -tf music.tar
practice/
practice/blues
practice/folk
practice/jazz
```

[The manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#failing-commands) the `--strip-components` option

> allow you to strip away a certain number of leading directory components

and

> ```
> tar --extract --file=music.tar --strip-components=1 folk
> ```
>
> will extract the file ‘`folk`’ into the current working directory.

But when I run this command on Ubuntu, I got this error

```
tar: folk: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

And my tar version is 1.34.
Besides, I got file folk extracted successfully when I executed the command below

```
tar --extract --file=music.tar --strip-components=1 practice/folk
```

Did I have some misunderstanding about the manual and option `--strip-components`?
Or is there something wrong with the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular example is wrong - you still need to specify the full path of the file inside the archive. Otherwise, given a tar file like:

```
$ tar -tf foo.tar
a/
a/folk
b/folk
b/blues
```

There would be no way for `tar` to tell which file you meant with `tar --extract --file=foo.tar --strip-components=1 folk`.

The section documenting `--strip-components` ([6.7 Modifying File and Member Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#transform)) has a correct example:

> For example, suppose you have archived whole ‘`/usr`’ hierarchy to a
> tar archive named ‘`usr.tar`’. Among other files, this archive
> contains ‘`usr/include/stdlib.h`’, which you wish to extract to the
> current working directory. To do so, you type:
>
> ```
> $ tar -xf usr.tar --strip=2 usr/include/stdlib.h
> ```
>
> The option ‘`--strip=2`’ instructs tar to strip the two leading
> components (‘`usr/`’ and ‘`include/`’) off the file name.
>
> If you add the ‘`--verbose`’ (‘`-v`’) option to the invocation above,
> you will note that the verbose listing still contains the full file
> name, with the two removed components still in place.